# Query with STL set function

Tags: c++, set

I am new to C++ STL. In the below example

```
bool checkDuplicatesWithinK(int arr[], int n, int k)
{  
    set<int> myset;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (myset.find(arr[i]) != myset.end())
            return true;

        myset.insert(arr[i]);

        if (i >= k)
            myset.erase(arr[i-k]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here I am not able to understand below line

```
if (myset.find(arr[i]) != myset.end())
    return true;
```

`myset.find(arr[i])` is checking whether the element is present in the set. But why have they put the condition not equal to `myset.end()`?
I read the description of `myset.end()` and this will return the iterator value of the element following last element.

Comment: Look up what `find` returns

Comment: What does `std::set::find` return if the element is not present in the set?

Comment: The `std::set::find` function returns the `std::set::end` iterator if the item is not found. Just for the avoidance of doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Three mistakes.
- when return expression is called, the function ends and **won't** execute the expressions following  `return`.

- Wrong parameter passing to erase
- Do the redundant work

As for the third one, you can directly use the return value of `insert`, which is a `std::pair` and you can check the second menber to ensure whether insert is done or not.

And I think that it's no need for you to check if insert has succeeded.

What you want is all inside http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: and although I pointed out your mistake, i still dont know what you really want to do, please edit your question.